# How can I call a method in a view model from the App.xaml.cs or an external background service project in the same solution

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, cortana, app.xaml

I am trying to call a method in a View Model from a background service that is hosting Cortana. 
I am unsure how to link up either the background service or App.xaml.cs to call a method in any view model whilst adhering to MVVM. Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks

I was thinking in the App.xaml.cs I could set up events that get called and invoke methods in the viewmodel by registering with that event

Comment: Cortana is a cloud service - how are  _you_ hosting it?

Comment: Please provide more info about the whole solution. Is this background service an [in-process or out-of-process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks#in-process-and-out-of-process-background-tasks) background task ? What was your solution for the communication between the two? What have you tried?

Comment: At the moment I am using the Voice Command Service to write custom commands in an XML file. When those commands are queried to Cortana, in the App.xaml.cs file I have overridden the OnActivated method and handle things such as the word or command set the command comes from.

Comment: In my solution, I simply want to call methods that reside in any of the View Models. At the moment I have a class that is known to the project and I have set up different events to handle specific calls. I just want to know if there is a better MVVM way? Thanks again